# Retrieve hardcoded string in WinDev compiled app

Tags: x64dbg, exe

I wrote an application with WinDev allowing you to open encrypted PDFs without the user having to enter or know the password.

This of course only works with PDFs that I have encrypted myself, always with the same password.

I would like to know how it is possible to recover this password (hardcoded in clear) from the compiled program.

I tried (several days...) with x64dbg but can't find anything that match with the password I defined.

Here is a link to the compiled program and an encrypted PDF file: https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ajc-YoF1UjJSiQZnTueRPUe1_C9x?e=MWIQ0d

The code I had to write couldn't be simpler, it's simply a call to the PDF_Main function:

```
PDF_Main.Ouvre(fSélecteur("", "", "Sélectionnez un fichier...", "PDF" + TAB + "*.pdf", "*.pdf"), "thePDFPasswordInClearString")
```